# How to fix Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I've built a Server side with Web-API calls to get data from Angular app,
My register page is getting the data fine but it never reaches the server-side,
The following error keeps occurring:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:58972/api/user/. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).[Learn More]
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:58972/api/user/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
>
> ERROR 
>   Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:58972/api/user/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:58972/api/user/: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }

Answer (score 0):

Add config.EnableCors(); in Register method in WebApiConfig.cs file

In angular side add the "access-control-allow-origin" HttpHeader

**If you are using owin with token base authentication then**

install this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/ and add app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); in Startup File under configuration method.

Comment: hey I was trying to put the method EnablCors(), but the config doesn't have it, should I implement it?, and where exactly i need to put the HttpHeader?

Comment: are you using owin token based authentication?

Comment: Please add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors from nuget. Sorry I haven't mentioned that in original answer.

Comment: Steps 
1. Add nuget package  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. add config.EnableCors(); in WebApiConfig.cs file under Register method.
3. add [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] on top of your method